# Merge to various type List in to new List Type

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge

**I have 2 list**

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids, IEnumerable<Guid> GuidIds
```

for sample data

```
IEnumerable<int> ids1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 };
IEnumerable<Guid> guidIds = new List<Guid>() { new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F94"), new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F96"), new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F97") };
```

and a class

```
public class ClassEnd
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid GuidId { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to merge into this by Linq query

```
IEnumerable<ClassEnd> mergeList = new List<ClassEnd>()
            {
                new ClassEnd() { Id = 1, CompanyId = new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F94") },
                new ClassEnd() { Id = 2, CompanyId = new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F96") },
                new ClassEnd() { Id = 3, CompanyId = new Guid("F44D7A64-8BDE-41E1-810F-B24377AD7F97") }
            };
```

Could you please help me with how to merge like the above "mergeList" by using Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lists are of the same size - it can be easily achieved with [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0):

```
var classEnds = ids1
    .Zip(guidIds, (i, guid) => new ClassEnd
    {
        Id = i,
        GuidId = guid
    })
    .ToList();
```